# i dont know how to get .htaccess to work in my page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

OK, so lets see i have a working link

```
http://hellow/app/view/apps.php?c=BANK&nom=LOLx3&n=1016
```

And i have this htaccess script for my link:

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=([^\&]*)
>
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nom=([^\&]*)
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} n=([^\&]*) 
>   RewriteRule apps.php$ %1/%2/%3? [NC]

I tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) so it works perfectly.

My doubt comes when i put this script in my .htacces ,who is in the same folder as my index.php. I will explain what i´m doing so tell me what is wrong.

- 1.I paste the script above in my .htaccess file.
- 2.I am trying to access with this link==>
  `http://hellow/app/view/apps.php?c=BANK&nom=LOLx3&n=1016`
- 3.The server gives me a 404 Error i think this is fine
- 4.Then i am trying to access with this link==>`http://hellow/app/view/Bank/LOLx3/1016`
- 5.And my server gives me a 404 Error
- 6.If a comment all that script in my .htacces everything is working like before.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: `I tested here so it works perfectly` I doubt that. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=([^\&])` (and the subsequent `RewriteCond`) can't match anything in `http://hellow/app/view/Bank/LOLx3/1016`

Comment: @Ejay u didnt read all this is the link http://hellow/app/view/apps.php?c=BANK&nom=LOLx3&n=1016

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 RewriteEngine on   
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=([^&]*)&nom=([^&]*)&n=([^&]*) [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^apps\.php$ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ apps.php?c=$1&nom=$2&n=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: i just tested the solution above and the script doesnt work. Thanks anyway